# Will a Mazda 6 GH 2009 2.5 L5 engine also fit a Mazda 6 2005?

Tags: engine, mazda, mazda-6, replacements, compatibility

I’m Wanting to know if an engine taken out of a Mazda 6 GH 2009 can be fitted/is compatible with a 2005 Mazda 6.? Are there any other makes/models of engine that would work for me or anything else I should be aware of to swap out my Mazda 6 engine ? Thanks (:

Comment: Anything can be made to fit if you have 4 things : skills, time, money and tools. Check other questions on here.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!